# Flash/As3 won't autostart

Tags: flash, flash-cs5

First of all, Flash/AS3 newbie here.

I create a small animation with ActionScript (basically fadeIn/fadeOut at different interval of different images). When I view in FlashPlayer directly it work when I view in browsers (any) I need to "click" inside the application for the fadeIn to start.

In my application I use this : stage.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, launch);
so I guessed it was caused because by defautl the application is not activated, my question is how can I make the animation start at loading without needing to click on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try different events.. like ENTER_FRAME (don't forget to remove it if you entered the function)..

Comment: *Feels dumb*, I tried it with ENTER_FRAME already but totally forgot to remove it as it is called really often, it now works! Thanks